# Regex for detecting preceeding and proceeding lowercase letters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a particular pattern in my strings and my knowledge of regex is quite basic. To find lower case letters I can use `[a-z0-9]+` but how would I go about finding the preceding and proceding characters?

Allowed examples:
`(A)`, `AB`, `ABC`, `[ABC]`, `.AB'` , `@ABCD#`. In essence only uppercase characters(any length), or uppercase(any length) with preceding or proceding or both(front and back), special chars.
Not Allowed:
`abABCaa` , `ABCaa` , `aaAB` , `123ABC` , `12ABGGabc` , `aaBaa` etc. In essence uppercase letters(any length) with preceding or proceding or both, alphabets or numbers.

How can I write a regex that filters either the allowed examples or the not allowed examples? 
Hope I am clear

Comment: How are `(BBA)` and `[BB'` valid strings?

Comment: In my applications 'special' case, having special chars before and after the uppercase is of no harm!

Comment: You mean `(` and `'` need to be allowed?  I thought you were saying your code currently allows these, but that it was wrong.  So are there any other "special" cases that need to be allowed?

Comment: Or, in other words, any string that doesn't *entirely*  consist of uppercase letters is OK?

Comment: @Sepster yea they need to be allowed!

Comment: I want to allow only uppercase letters along with any special characters, but no lower case chars or chars or numbers.

Comment: Mate, can you please edit your question to include a list of examples of what needs to be allowed, and a list of examples that should not be allowed.  Your question is too ambiguous at this stage, apparently ;-)

Comment: sorry about that..I will edit it.

Comment: @Salmanmahmood Updated to match! ;-)

Comment: Mate, are `aaaB` and `Baaa` valid matches or not.  Your opening paragraph suggests (to me, at least) that they are valid.

Comment: I think he described in the opening paragraph the case for what is not allowed.

Comment: @Sednus The problem is we're both _thinking_ what is/isn't allowed, he's not telling us explicitly.  Note his explicit examples don't support _either_ your interpretation OR mine! ;-)

Comment: I've -1'd this question Salman... With all due respect unless you clean up the question this record isn't going to be of any value to anyone in future looking for a similar solution; It's simply not clear what you asked (despite my attempts to get clarification). In particular, are `aaB` and `Baa` valid or not? IMO the accepted answer doesn't line up with the question, so you need to update the question to clarify either way.  I'll happily remove the downvote once this is done.

Comment: check it now and see if it makes sense. I think you misunderstood that there is only one uppercase letter per word which was not the case.

Comment: Wow.  This question is about 180 degrees from where it started ;-)  Downvote removed.  Out of interest, what's the use-case you're modelling with this?

Comment: Thanks! thats why I hate regex. One needs a regex to explain the regex he wants ;). I have got stock exchange company symbols which are always in capital form. I am getting these symbols from different RSS feeds and sometimes they are like `[TH]` `(TH)` `TH` or `TH®`. Needed to differentiate them from usual words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will match 3 groups: the Matched uppercase, the characters preceding it and the characters after it. If groups are not desired, just remove the parenthesis.

```
([^a-z0-9]*)([A-Z]+)([^a-z0-9]*)
```

For more information about matching and grouping please refer to the proper [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) .
Also, a suggestion for [testing regex online](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: that was a mistake. Sorry I meant `A-Z` for uppercase letters. Thanks

Comment: My +1 for your persistence @Sednus.  Glad you got it over the line for us :-)

Comment: One minor nitpick: `[A-Z]+` will always only match one character, so you might as well drop the `+`.

Comment: You mean that capital letters will be matched in the first group and the second group will only match one always, yes, it is true. Nice! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about simple:

```
\b[A-Z]+\b
```

That will match uppercase letters surrounded by other characters than word character

Comment: `aaBaaa` is supposed to be a valid input

Comment: @Sednus No it's not according to his examples.

Comment: @Sednus: No it is not, see last sentence of the question.

Comment: @Sednus: no problem. But it'll be nice to remove the downvote.

Comment: Im locked. I will ASAP, I suggest you make and edit so that you unlock me

Comment: However, this will not match `[ABC]`or `(AB)`

Comment: @Sednus: yes it will. It'll match all examples given by OP and not match what is unwanted.

Comment: so `\b` will match `[` or `(`?. i dont have to do something like (\\[[A-Z]+\\])|(\\([A-Z]+\\))|(\b[A-Z]+\b) . (escaping the `[]` and `()` )

Comment: But this won't cover the initial requirement outlined in the OP's first paragraph "I need to know if an uppercase letter is preceded or proceded by lowercase letters or numbers."

Comment: Also /b doesn't work as intended in Java (apparently). I tried it. It does work in Javascript for example.

Comment: @Sednus: Double escape it in java i.e. `\\b`

Comment: yes thats not working for me either. going to try your solution @Sednus

Comment: My DV removed, my interpretation of requirements was wrong with re to pre/proceeding lower-case/numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier. Simply check for a match against:

```
"^\\p{P}*[A-Z]+\\p{P}*$"
```

`\p{P}` matches any punctuation character.

`^` and `$` can be dropped if you're using the `.matches()` method.

So this matches `AAB`, `#A`, `A.` and fails `1A`, `aAa`, `aA` and `Aa`.

Comment: Does \p{P} also matches symbols like `[` , `@` , `(`?

Comment: But this won't cover the initial requirement outlined in the OP's first paragraph "I need to know if an uppercase letter is preceded or proceded by lowercase letters or numbers."

Comment: @Sepster: If there is only punctuation (or nothing) around uppercase letter, then there are no lowercase letters there. QED. That's what he wants to exclude, so if this regex matches, that requirement is fulfilled.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ah, difference in interpretation then.  I took his statement to mean he _wants_ `aaB` and `Baa` to be valid (as he said _is_, he didn't say _is not_).  But yep, I'll remove my down-vote because that's an issue with the question, not your answer! (edit: when I'm not locked).

Comment: @Sepster: Oh well, we probably deserve it, answering a vague question like this :)

Answer (score -1):

not sure this can be done with regex. try it algorithmically by comparing :

- start loop all characters of the string (alpha chars):

  CurCharIsUpper = (curchar.uppercase == curchar.lower) ? false: true;
  if (PrevCharIsUpper == CurCharIsUpper) blahblah;
  PrevCharIsUpper = CurCharIsUpper;
- end loop

Comment: I believe it can be (refer my answer)... but don't disagree it might be more intuitive to do this algorithmically in certain situations.